# take name of tab for TabLayoutPanel

Tags: gwt

I'm using `TabLayoutPanel`.

```
TabLayoutPanel content = new TabLayoutPanel();
FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();
content.add(fp,"one");
content.add(fp,"two");
content.add(fp,"tree");
content.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent event) {
    //
    //How can I take name of selected tab ("one" or "two" ...)
    //
    }
});
```

Comment: By the way, you add the same FlowPanel three times to this widget, so all of the tabs will look the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally text is converted to either [HTML](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTML.html) or [Label](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Label.html) widget when component is added in [TabLayoutPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html)

Try below code in `SelectionHandler`

```
Widget widget=content.getTabWidget(content.getSelectedIndex());

if(widget instanceof Label){
    System.out.println(((Label)widget).getText());
}else if(widget instanceof HTML){
    System.out.println(((HTML)widget).getHTML());
} else {
    System.out.println(widget.getTitle());
}
```

**Note:** Always use generic form of [SelectionHandler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/SelectionHandler.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can get a selected widget:

```
FlowPanel fp = contents.getWidget(contents.getSelectedIndex());
```

Inside a selection handler you can use:

```
FlowPanel fp = contents.getWidget(event.getSelectedItem());
```

Comment: Yes, but fp not contain name оf selected tab. I need take text "one".